# Matlab Convolution Array with vector row by row - Galois Field(2)

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, convolution

Let's say I have array  `A(n,k)` and vector `b(1,4)`. Matrix and vector's context are on Galois Field (2).

Is there any way to convolute each row of A with vector b without for loop?

For example if A is of size   `(4,5)` then the command should do the following:

```
    conv(A(1,:),b)

    conv(A(2,:),b)

    conv(A(3,:),b)

    conv(A(4,:),b)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a "Gallua field"?! Why did you revert my correction?

Comment: @LuisMendo am sorry my mistake, can you re-correct it??? I did not notice it was edited and I thought I was mistaken

Comment: You mean Galois field, right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field

Comment: yes yes ! my bad sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert `A` to a cell array and then use `cellfun` to apply your function to every element of the cell array, such as:

```
cellA = num2cell(A, 2) % creates a cell array where each element is a row of A
result = cellfun(@(row)(conv(row, b)), cellA);
```

Here `@(row)(conv(row, b))` is an anonymous function that takes one element of the cell array and applies your `conv` function to it and your `b` vector

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me say that it is not working because A and b are gf (gallua field) type variables. I must come up with something else. Let me add that the error pops up when using cellfun!!